# How to retrain an Image Classifier with new classes and keep old classes

Tags: image, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to make an image classifier that can identify how likely it is that an image is an image of a watermelon. To do this I followed the flower classifier example here: https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retrainin and trained the model using this command

```
python retrain.py --image_dir ~/flower_photos
```

The problem I found when trying this classifier out is that it only classifies among the new classes, that is the flower classes in this case. So when I tried to classify an image of a dog (which I know is present in the Inception module) it classified it as a rose

```
python label_image.py \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--input_layer=Placeholder \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=/images/dog.jpg
```

Result

```
roses 0.7626607
tulips 0.12247563
dandelion 0.071335025
sunflowers 0.028395686
daisy 0.0151329385
```

How could I use TensorFlow to extend the model with an additional class instead of creating a new model with only the new classes?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is join the two datasets and train them together or just leave the classes of model you are retraining in the possible classes and add a few images of those classes to the dataset just for the model to not forget what it already learned.

Comment: I don't understand exactly how to do this. How do I join the datasets? Or how do I leave the classes of the inception model I'm retraining in the possible classes? :)